# convert pandas dataframe column into multiple columns based on groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have large pandas dataframe with two columns `rider_ID` and `person_ID` given as:

```
ride_ID  person_ID  
 ride_1    person1   
 ride_1    person2    
 ride_1    person3    
 ride_2    person1    
 ride_2    person4    
 ride_3    person1    
 ride_3    person5    
 ride_3    person2    
 ride_3    person3  
 .....     ......
 .....     ......
```

For each unique `ride_ID` the number of `person_ID` could be anything either 2 or 20 or 100.  All, I want to apply groupby on column `ride_ID` such that column `person_ID` will reflected into multiple columns with columns name as `person_ID1` till `person_IDn`. Expected output as;

```
ride_ID  person_ID1 person_ID2   person_ID3   person_ID4   person_ID5 ....... person_IDn 

 ride_1   person1    person2      person3      NaN         NaN        ......                           
 ride_2   person1    NaN          NaN          person4     NaN        ......     
 ride_3   person1    person2      person3      NaN         person5
```

Comment: How do you relate "person_ID1" with "person1"? Is it the suffix "1"? Does "person_ID" always has that format?

Comment: @AzharKhan The column names would be based on maximum number of `persons` for unique `ride_ID`. Lets say, `ride_44` has maximum ride which is `50` then column names will range from `person_ID1` to `person_ID50` and then for each ride the corresponding person will marked.

Comment: How do you relate "person_ID" with value in that column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pivot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). For that, create a column "person_IDx" with values in serial fashion "person_ID1, person_ID2, ..., person_IDn" for each "ride_ID" type:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["ride_1","person1"],["ride_1","person2"],["ride_1","person3"],["ride_2","person1"],["ride_2","person4"],["ride_3","person1"],["ride_3","person5"],["ride_3","person2"],["ride_3","person3"]], columns=["ride_ID","person_ID"])

df["person_IDx"] = 1

df["person_IDx"] = df.groupby("ride_ID")["person_IDx"].transform("cumsum").apply(lambda x: f"person_ID{x}")

df = df.pivot(index="ride_ID", columns="person_IDx", values="person_ID").reset_index().rename_axis(columns={"person_IDx":""})

[Out]:
  ride_ID person_ID1 person_ID2 person_ID3 person_ID4
0  ride_1    person1    person2    person3        NaN
1  ride_2    person1    person4        NaN        NaN
2  ride_3    person1    person5    person2    person3
```